# compile error: cannot find symbol: In, StdIn and StdOut

Tags: java

The code is from 
http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/11model/BinarySearch.java.html for Algorithms textbook.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BinarySearch {

    // precondition: array a[] is sorted
    public static int rank(int key, int[] a) {
        int lo = 0;
        int hi = a.length - 1;
        while (lo <= hi) {
            // Key is in a[lo..hi] or not present.
            int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
            if      (key < a[mid]) hi = mid - 1;
            else if (key > a[mid]) lo = mid + 1;
            else return mid;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] whitelist = In.readInts(args[0]);

        Arrays.sort(whitelist);

        // read key; print if not in whitelist
        while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
            int key = StdIn.readInt();
            if (rank(key, whitelist) == -1)
                StdOut.println(key);
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error

```
$ javac BinarySearch.java 
BinarySearch.java:44: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable In
location: class BinarySearch
        int[] whitelist = In.readInts(args[0]);
                          ^
BinarySearch.java:49: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable StdIn
location: class BinarySearch
        while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
                ^
BinarySearch.java:50: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable StdIn
location: class BinarySearch
            int key = StdIn.readInt();
                      ^
BinarySearch.java:52: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable StdOut
location: class BinarySearch
                StdOut.println(key);
                ^
4 errors
```

Comment: Yes @Jon is right. Its showing error in my editor.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Classes `StdIn`, `StdOut` and `In` aren't part of the standard Java libraries. They're support classes provided to go along with the Princeton course.

From the [1.1 Programming Model](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/11model/) page linked in the source code:

> Standard input and standard output. [`StdIn.java`](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdIn.html) and [`StdOut.java`](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdOut.html) are libraries for reading in numbers and text from standard input and printing out numbers and text to standard output. Our versions have a simpler interface than the corresponding Java ones (and provide a few tecnical improvements).
>
> ...
>
> [`In.java`](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/11model/In.java.html) and [`Out.java`](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/11model/Out.java.html) are object-oriented versions that support multiple input and output streams, including reading from a file or URL and writing to a file.

So if you want to use the binary search code as-is, you'll need to download those files.

Comment: Is it really directly use full for our program ? Please help me .

Comment: @JDeveloper: I don't understand your question completely (it's not clear), but you can use those classes yourself for working with `BinarySearch.java`, yes. See the licence terms if you want to use them elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet! I basically downloaded In, StdIn and StdOut java files in the same directory and it worked out.

Comment: Updated 11.09.2017 - [Q&A](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/) section there is [stdlib-package.jar](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/stdlib-package.jar) named package packaged version file that can be used for reference

Answer (score 9):

If you have already set up the environment recommended for the course, only add this lines to your java file

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdIn;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdOut;
```

Comment: I did this using DrJava and the program compiled. Thanks. My question is how do you include the edu..princeton.cs.algs4 package when using eclipse? I could not get it to compile using eclipse

Comment: @YonatanSimson In the _Troubleshooting_ section of [the instruction page](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/mac/), it says that _**Can I use a different IDE?** Yes you can use another IDE (such as Eclipse) but you will have to configure the IDE properties yourself (such as the classpath)._ Thus I suggest you compile the file in terminal since it would be more convenient (only if you have installed the DrJava through `algs4.zip`)

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me when using the latest method outlined in the algs4 website which is with the IntelliJ IDE.

Answer (score 4):

You can replace then with

**Output:**

```
 System.out.println(key);
```

**Input**

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String Key= null;
try {
     Key = reader.readLine();
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

They are using custom libraries to print the value to console(Presumably)
You can redirect the output to console.

Answer (score 4):

StdIn and In are custom Libraries that are included within the algs4 class download. 
Execute the program with the command java-algs4 instead of just java and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to use `StdIn` and `StdOut` by including [`stdlib.jar`](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/) in my project and it is properly placed in the classpath, but I cannot make it work by adding:

- import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdIn;
- import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdOut;

in my own java file.

I find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320092/how-to-use-jar-files-without-package-information). I just removed package info in my java files and without any import info I can use `StdIn` and `StdOut` in my project since all my java files and the `StdIn`, `StdOut` are all in the default package.

By the way, It is a bad practice to do so in a real-world production-ready project.

Answer (score 0):

The `stdlib.jar` is better to be placed in the `src` folder for ease of finding the path. If you are using any IDE, please add the classpath of the library.

If you are confronted with the problem that the `stdlib` is the default library, please use these commands to compile and run the codes.

**Compile**

```
javac -cp .;<YOUR\PATH\OF\THE\LIB\stdlib.jar> yourProgram.java
```

**Run**

```
java -cp .;<YOUR\PATH\OF\THE\LIB\stdlib.jar> yourProgram <arguments>
```

If you follow my suggestion, then the path will be only `stdlib.jar` or more organised `lib\stdlib.jar`.

Ref link: https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/

Answer (score -2):

You should use `System.in` and `System.out` instead of `StdIn` and `StdOut`.
 Create an `ObjectInputStream` wrapping the System input stream the following way:
`ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(System.in);`
It has a `readInt` method, amd to check if it is empty, you must catch the `EOFException`.