# Error in piping java programs

Tags: java, piping, drjava

I have a class RandomSeq which prints "args[0]" random doubles and a class Average which prints the average of StdIn. I'm using DrJava for writing codes and compiling.I've downloaded the StdIn and out libraries and put them in the same folder of my classes. I'm learning Java.

First problem is in the "Interactions" section of DrJava. When I write `java RandomSeq 10 > data.txt` instead of creating the text file, it prints the output. Why?
Then I typed the same command in Windows command line. It created the txt file successfully.

Now I want to pipe the output of RandomSeq 10 to the input of Average. Writing `java RandomSeq 10 | java Average`
in DrJava's Interactions section causes funny behaviour. Writing it in cmd prints the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: StdIn
        at Average.main(Average.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: StdIn
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

Even `java Average < data.txt` shows the same error.Why?

```
public class RandomSeq
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(Math.random());
        }
    }
}




public class Average
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        double S = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while (!StdIn.isEmpty())
        {
            double n = StdIn.readDouble();
            S += n;
            i++;
        }
        S = S/i;
        //StdOut.printf("The mean is %.3f", S);
        StdOut.println(S);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the fully-qualified name of `StdIn`? Is it on your classpath?

Comment: "When I write java RandomSeq 10 > data.txt instead of creating the text file" - where are you writing this in? :)

Comment: @AndyTurner I'm new to java. What do you mean by "fully-qualified name" of StdIn? I've downloaded it from here: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/15inout/StdIn.java

Comment: @AndyTurner And as I said, StdIn and StdOut are in the same folder of my classes

Comment: @matrixanomaly I've mentioned it in my post: In "Interactions" section of DrJava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [related question on StdIn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207427/compile-error-cannot-find-symbol-in-stdin-and-stdout). `StdIn` is not a standard java library, as you mentioned that you're following the Princeton course, that `StdIn.java` is provided by the course, you probably need to compile `StdIn.java` as well, with the command `javac StdIn.java`to generate a `StdIn.class` file, this will solve the `Class not Found Exception`. (the second issue)

As to the problem of you writing `java RandomSeq 10 > data.txt` in DrJava (which I asked for clarification because I didn't realize DrJava is an IDE, thought it was a book), is because the `Interactions` section most likely directly gives the input to your program, meaning it passes whatever you type in there as `args[]` for your `main` function.

The output is printed because you call `system.out.println` in your code, and DrJava just takes that output and prints it out to the screen, and won't pipe to your `data.txt` file. I would recommend that since you're using course material that requires stuff like piping to interact with your program in the command line.

Lastly `java RandomSeq 10 | java Average` is the same as doing `java RandomSeq 10` and then taking that output into `java Average`, which the second command is the same as you doing `java Average < data.txt`, the error isn't because of how you're piping it, but just because of `StdIn` not being present as a compiled `.class` file.

Comment: Compiling StdIn.java and StdOut.java solved the issue. Thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 2):

`StdIn` is not from a built-in Java library.  It is part of a 3rd party library that is contained in a `stdlib.jar` file that can be downloaded from [here](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/stdlib.jar).

The path to that `JAR` file must be in the `-CLASSPATH` option of your command-line `javac` and `java` invocations. The **Using the standard libraries** section of [this page](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/) shows you how to do this; the `-cp` option is just shorthand for `-CLASSPATH`. It is important to learn how to put libraries onto your `CLASSPATH`, as you'll eventually be doing it all the time with Java.

Your `Average.java` code must also `import` the `StdIn` class.  Since `StdIn` does not reside in a named package, you just say `import StdIn;` at the top of your code.

Alternatively, you could just use  `System.in`, rather than this library.  You probably also want a higher level stream construct around that.  [Here's a nice example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-the-standard-input-in-java/).

Comment: But in the link below in the "Connecting two programs" section: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/15inout/  , none of these prerequisites are mentioned :-|

Comment: No problem. I just condensed my answer for future use. It will enable you to use `StdIn` without needing to compile it.