# Significance of 'In' in Java

Tags: java

I've copied the following method from page 173 of [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032157351X).

```
public class ThreeSum
{
  public static int count(int[] a)
  { // Count triples that sum to 0.
    int N = a.length;
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
      for (int j = i+1; j < N; j++)
        for (int k = j+1; k < N; k++)
          if (a[i] + a[j] + a[k] == 0)
            cnt++;
    return cnt;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int[] a = In.readInts(args[0]); // error here
    StdOut.println(count(a)); // and here
  }
}
```

The `In.readInts` causes an error. Do I need to be including a library to access the 'In' object? (third last line)

Comment: import scanner. maybe. look at the book, they probably use the same method for input all around, so just check the beginning.

Comment: It seems you copied code from some where. In is nothing in java. In in the example you copied from could be a stream or some custom class.

Comment: answer is here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207427/compile-error-cannot-find-symbol-in-stdin-and-stdout]

Comment: A *perfect* duplicate: well spotted.

Comment: wow thanks same textbook and everything

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `In` is not a original Java class, but probably an API/Library class from your book. Look at one of the first pages, probably you will find some information about the class.